# How to set Toggle button in Cocos2d 3.0?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

CCMenu,CCMenuItem,CCMenuItemToggle toggle is Deprecated in Cocos2d 3.0.I want to set toggle button in cocos2d 3.0.

I found below method in 3.0 But it's not working.

```
CCButton *soundOnBtn == [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@""
                            spriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"soundOn.png"]
                 highlightedSpriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"soundOnSelected.png"]
                    disabledSpriteFrame:nil];

CCButton *soundOffBtn= [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@""
                              spriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"soundOff.png"]
                   highlightedSpriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"soundOffSelected.png"]
                      disabledSpriteFrame:nil];
```

Pls, help me...
  Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I assume you want a toggle button to enable/disable the sound.

You can do this only by having one button with two states: Sound enabled (not selected) and sound disabled (selected).

Try this, maybe you will still have to change some parameters when it is in selected state:

```
CCButton *soundTriggerBtn = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@""
                        spriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"soundOn.png"]
             highlightedSpriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"soundOff.png"]
                disabledSpriteFrame:nil];

soundTriggerBtn.togglesSelectedState = YES;
```

I hope it helps